# how to measure quality of sharpening in images

Tags: image, image-processing, sharp, mse, deconvolution

I have a distorted (blurred image) and I perform several deconvolution algorithms on it to sharpen it (Richardson lucy, regularized inverse filter, tikhonov miller). And i want to measure each performance by calculating the MSE (mean square error). However I don’t have a reference or an ideal image where I can compare my result.
is there a way to measure quality of sharpening when a reference image is not available ?

Comment: perhaps this is a topic for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/